# How to limit .once('value) in firebase-admin node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

How do I limit .once('value') in firebase-admin?

Code:

```
async function GetStuff(limit, page){
    const data = await ref.limitToFirst(parseInt(limit)).once('value')
    return data.val();
}
```

I wanted to create a page system, where a it sends request for a limited amount of data, and the user can change the page to get different data, but for some reason, I can't get it to work.

The code above only gets the first 20(when limit is 20), but how can I make it start at 20, so I can make this page feature.

I thought:

Code:

```
async function GetStuff(limit, page){
    const data = await ref.startAt(limit*page).limitToFirst(parseInt(limit)).once('value')
    return data.val();
}
```

Comment: *"The code above keeps fetches no data"* - no idea what this actually means.  What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: @DougStevenson Please view update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to review the [relevant documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries).  It looks like you're trying to pass the offset of a child to `startAt`, but that's not how `startAt` works.  It accepts the actual value of the child to start at.  Pagination by offset index is not supported.

The way you use `startAt` is typically passing the last sorted value retrieved by the prior query (or, if you don't want to retrieve that value again, 1 + that value, or a string that is lexically greater than the last string received.  As such, some data sets might actually be difficult to paginate if they have the same sorted value repeated many times.

Comment: So if I update the data set with a ascending ID(numbers, 1,2,3...), I should be able to use startAt?

Comment: Sure, as long as you order the query by that value so they don't appear out of order.